# Ordering a 2 bar plot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data set as below and I have created a graph with below code as suggested in a previous question. What I want to do is order the bars by rankings rather than team names. Is that possible to do in ggplot?

```
Team Names  PLRankingsReverse   Grreserve

Liverpool   20  20
Chelsea 19  19
Manchester City 15  18
Arsenal 16  17
Tottenham   18  16
Manchester United   8   15
Everton 10  14
Watford 13  13
Burnley 17  12
Southampton 9   11
WBA 11  10
Stoke   4   9
Bournemouth 12  8
Leicester   7   7
Middlesbrough   14  6
C. Palace   6   5
West Ham    1   4
Hull    3   3
Swansea 5   2
Sunderland  2   1
```

And here is the code:

```
alldata <- read.csv("premierleague.csv")
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
alldata <- melt(alldata)
ggplot(alldata, aes(x = Team.Names, y= value, fill = variable), xlab="Team   Names") +
geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.5, position = "dodge")
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you go through the documentation of geom_bar() ? It already has an example of what you are asking for!

Comment: also, share an example of data for us to work on directly!

Comment: as mentionned by joel.wilson the last example in ?geom_bar() should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have checked the documentation but couldn't figure out as I have same values in same column so couldn't sort by values. And also I have updated the data table up in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to sort your data frame prior to melting and capture the order. You can then use this to set the limit order on `scale_x_discrete`, or you can factor `Team Name` in your `aes` string.

### Using factor:

```
ordr <- order(alldata$`Team Names`, alldata$PLRankingsReverse, decreasing = TRUE)

alldata <- melt(alldata)

ggplot(alldata, aes(x = factor(`Team Name`, ordr),  y = value, fill = variable) + 
  labs(x = "Team Name") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .5, position = "dodge")
```

### Using scale_x_discrete:

```
ordr <- alldata$`Team Name`[order(alldata$PLRankingsReverse, decreasing = TRUE)]

alldata <- melt(alldata)

ggplot(alldata, aes(x = `Team Name`, y = value, fill = variable) + 
  labs(x = "Team Name") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width =. 5, position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = ordr)
```

Comment: Thanks Jake, was able to do it with scale_x_discrete. Huge help :)